# Configuring VPN in a virtual machine

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vpn, vmware-player

I have a company machine with is also being used on a client network.  For accessing some (but not all) facilities of our company we are required to use VPN A (managed by Cisco AnyConnect).  To access some (but not all) of the client's network we need to use VPN B (managed by Pulse Secure).  Naturally we need to access the facilities of both our company and the client at the same time and the VPNs fight about who's in charge.

I can move the client's work off into a VmWare machine, where the VPN B works fine, but as soon as I start our company VPN, A, the VM loses its internet adapter.

I notice I have a number of options, some with advanced options, within the VmWare configuration for the VM: bridged, nat, host-only, custom, lan segment.  Might one of these enable me to bypass the VPN on the host and enable the VM to talk direct to the network?

Comment: Your issues are due to the configuration of VPN A.  As an end user of the VPN there really isn't a great deal you can do about it.  A possible solution is to run both VPNs within a VM.

Comment: Retagged from [vmware] (a firm, probably relevaqnt if you are interested in it stocks, directros etc) to [VMware player]. I could be wrong though and maybe you have [vmware-workstation] or even ESX. IN that case please retag appropriately.